# print matching lines from file1 and file2

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file1.txt and file2.txt i would like to print the matching lines to a new files

file1.txt

```
FOMPING00002015
FOMPING00008750 
FOMPING00003379 
FOMPING00009073
FOMPING00007164 
FOMPING00009598
```

file2.txt

```
>FOMPING00013293 Protein of unknown function
ATGCCCTGCTCGTCGCTCGAGCGGGATCATAGCCAGCATGAAGTTATACCGTCATCGCAG
AGCCAGGAACGCGACTTTGTGCCGCCTAATGGTGACATCAGGAGTCGGGCGAGAACGACA
TCCGACGAAATTGTACCCACATCGCAG
>FOMPING00003379 Protein of unknown function
ATGCCCTGCTCGTCGCTCGAGCGGGATCATAGCCAGCATGAAGTTATACCGTCATCGCAG
AGCCAGGAACGCGACTTTGTGCCGCCTAATGGTGACATCAGGAGTCGGGCGAGAACGACA
TCCGACGAAATTGTACCCACATCGCAGTA
>FOMPING00009073 Protein of unknown function 
ATGTCCTCTTGGTCTGGTTCTTCTTACCCTCCACCTCCACGCGCACGTTCGCGCTCTCGC
TCCCCTTATCGTGGGTCTTATCCTGCGAGACCCGGGTATCCAGAGCCTGGATACTCGCAG
>FOMPING00000581 Similar to mcs4: Response regulator mcs4  
ATGTCCTCTTGGTCTGGTTCTTCTTACCCTCCACCTCCACGCGCACGTTCGCGCTCTCGC
TCCCCTTATCGTGGGTCTTATCCTGCGAGACCCGGGTATCCAGAGCCTGGATACTCGCAG
GATCCATACCGTGCCGACTGGGAGGCTTATGACAGAGAGCGCGCATGGGCCTCCTACGAG
```

I have tried few commands

```
grep -F file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

both the commands outputs just the first line from file2.txt

output.txt

```
>FOMPING00013293 Protein of unknown function
>FOMPING00000581 Similar to mcs4: Response regulator mcs4.
```

**I want the output file just like the file2.txt with sequences in it.**

Thank you

Comment: Diff can print out X lines after match with `-A X`.   Is the number of lines after each match constant?  If not, you'll have to parse `file2.txt` and match "headers" with their "sequence" lines.  But if it's always just one line, you can do `-A 1`.

Comment: Thank you. number of lines varies after each match.

Comment: Does headers in file2 literally start with `>`?

Comment: Yes every block starts with ">"

Comment: Of the three you list, `awk` is what you need.  But if I were doing this and similar things with arbitrary, "inconveniently" structured input data (briefly looking at your question history), I would skip `awk` and shoot straight to my favorite programming language.  `awk` is a very powerful tool but also antiquated.  In the modern age you'll (probably) enjoy modeling your data in something like golang/ruby/python/etc compared to awk.  I cannot tell you how to do this in `awk`.

Comment: And in your output you want this `>` to be removed?

Comment: it has to be present, i will be using that file for further analysis. so > is required

Comment: then you should also correct the `output.txt` in your question, since `>` is missing.

Comment: i have edited it now, both the file1 and file2. hope its clear now

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work ok in my tests. The trick is to use ">" as record / block separator.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next};$1 in a{print ">" $0}' file1.txt RS=">" file2.txt
#or alternativelly, due to the whitespace present in the end of each line of file1.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next};$1 in a{print ">" $0}' file1.txt RS=">" file2.txt
```

The position of `RS` in the end of awk, affects the file that comes after `RS`.
In my command, `file1` is parsed with default `RS="\n"` , but `file2` is parsed with `RS=">"`.

Comment: thank you, but the output has only one from the test file (>FOMPING00009073) but not the other one

Comment: @kapr0001 Your `file1.txt` has some space characters at the end of some lines. It should work if you remove these.

Comment: @Freddy i spent 15 minutes to realize that .... my solution was not working in the beginning due to this fact. Maybe is safer to use `{a[$1];next}` in the first part to be sure that white space at the end will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I realized the same (`a[$1]`). Btw., I upvoted your solution, very creative!

Comment: I couldn't realize there were white spaces in file one. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` with two input field separators `>` and the space character:

```
awk -F'[> ]' '{
  if (NR==FNR){
    a[$1]
  }
  else {
    if (substr($0,0,1) == ">"){
      printline=($2 in a)
    }
    if (printline){
      print
    }
  }
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

When the first file is processed, store the first field in an array.
When the second file is processed, test if the current line begins with `>` and set a flag `printline` testing if the second field is present in the array.
Print the current line if the flag is set.

Comment: It working on the test files, but i dont know for some reason its not working on my original files, will try to figure it out

Comment: it worked great. thank you